# How to prove that $|P(A)| + |P(B)| = 16$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$U =\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8\}$

$A =\{1,2,3\}$

$B =\{3,4,5,6,7\}$

$$|P(A)| + |P(B)| = 8 + 16 $$

($P(A)$ is the set of all the subsets of $A$.)

I thought that $|P(A)|$ meant all the elements in $A$ and in $A^{c} = 3 + 5 = 8$. But in that case $|P(B)|$ would also be equal to $8$ and not $16$. So what do they mean here?

Comment: $P(A)$ often means the set of all subsets of $A$, and $|X|$ is the number of elements in $X$. So in your example $|P(A)| = 2^3 = 8$ and $|P(B)| = 2^5 = 32$ . Then you can add them. But that's not a very sensible thing to do, so I suspect that you have misread the question, and that $P$ stands for probability and $P(A) = 3/8$ assuming you choose one number from $U$ at random. We really need more context to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a set $X$, $|X|$ is simply the number of elements in it, and $P(X)$ is the set whose elements are all the subsets of $X$. So $|P(X)|$ is the number of distinct subsets of $X$, which is always equal to $2^{|X|}$. (To see why this is, consider that for every element of $X$, a subset either has that element or it doesn't.)

Since $A$ has 3 elements, $|P(A)| = 2^{|A|} = 2^3 = 8$. Similarly, since $B$ has 5 elements, $|P(B)| = 2^{|B|} = 2^5 = 32$ (not sure where that 16 is coming from).

Comment: Thanks you are right! My bad should be $B =\begin{Bmatrix}3,4,5,6\end
{Bmatrix}$

Answer (score 0):

|S| generally means the number of elements present in the set S.

For this question P(A) is the set of all subsets of the set A. And therefore, |P(A)| is the number of subsets of A.

To find the number of subsets of a set,

Let a set S have n distinct elements in it. Now consider an array containing n zeros.
Now, you have to construct a subset. For each index i in the set S, if you want to include it in the subset, change the $i^th$ zero to one or just leave it as it is. So you have 2 choices for each element - include it in the subset, or don't include it.

Therefore for n elements, you totally have $2^n$ ways to form a subsets. Hence, there are totally 2^n subsets.

Here is an example,
S = {1, 2, 3}

{}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {1,2}, {1,3}, {2,3}, {1,2,3} ---> $2^3$ = 8 subsets.

This can also be denoted like this..
000, 100, 010, 001, 110, 101, 011, 111 (1 implies that the element in its position is included).

Now, |P(A)| = $2^3$ = 8 and |P(B)| = $2^5$ = 32

8 + 32 = 40.

Answer (score 0):

$P(A)$ stands for the power set and it is the set of all subsets of $A$

With the given information $$P(A)=2^3=8$$ and $$P(B)=2^5=32$$

you have probably misread the problem.