# Adding the cardinals of not disjoint sets ( without inclusion of one set in the other) : does cardinal arithmetics offer a formula?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, arithmetic

This question has been suggested to me by this post : 
[How to prove that $|P(A)| + |P(B)| = 16$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3241657/how-to-prove-that-pa-pb-16)

---

Suppose A and B are disjoint.

If I want to add the cardinal of P(A) and of P(B) , I cannot use this formula

```
                      #X + #Y = # ( X U Y )
```

for here my two sets are not disjoint ( two powersets always having at least one element in common).

Here I know that the sets P(A) and P(B) only have one element in common ( since A and B are disjoint).

Is there a formula of cardinal arithmetics that applies here?

Comment: You can “paint” each set a different color, so that they are now disjoint: take $P(A)\times\{0\}$ (“painting” $P(A)$ with the color $0$) and $P(B)\times\{1\}$. Now you have that $\#P(A)=\#(P(A)\times\{0\{)$, $\#P(B)=\#(P(B)\times\{1\})$, but $P(A)\times\{0\}$ is disjoint from $P(B)\times\{1\}$, so the sum of their cardinals is the cardinal of their (usual) union. But more generally, your formula should use the so-called “disjoint union”, not the union.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin. Thanks for answering. The trick is fine!

Answer (score 1):

For any sets $X$ and $Y$,  $|X\cup Y| = |X| + |Y| - |X\cap Y|$.

That is, you count up all the elements assuming they're all different, then you subtract the elements they have in common so that you don't double-count.

In particular, the power sets $P(A)$ and $P(B)$ of disjoint sets have one element in common—the empty set. So, count up the number of elements in each power set assuming they have nothing in common, then subtract the one element $(\varnothing)$ they have in common:

$$| P(A) \cup P(B)| = |P(A)| + |P(B)| - 1 = 2^{|A|} + 2^{|B|}-1$$